# Writing interceptors in CXF Webservices project

Tags: java, spring, cxf

How do I write a CXF interceptor to prevent execution of couple of Restful URL's based on some specific conditions. I know that I need to write an interceptor extending `URIMappingInterceptor`. The blocking has to be done based on the name of the url or function that will be called. I need to return immediately throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor` and using the message.get, get the url or uri and do validation Here is an example I used a long back.

```
public class RestInInterceptor extends AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(RestInInterceptor.class);

    public RestInInterceptor(String phase) {
        super(Phase.USER_STREAM);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RestInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.USER_STREAM);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        Endpoint endpoint = message.getExchange().getEndpoint();

        String output = "";

        // for uri key is org.apache.cxf.request.uri
        String url = (String) message.get("org.apache.cxf.request.url");

        if(!"".equals(url) && url.contains("KP1Service")){
            Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).entity("").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) .build();
            message.getExchange().put(Response.class, response);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```